# A few questions about dynamic memory allocation

Tags: arrays, c

1. If I dynamically define an array inside a loop, and give it different values each time, and I also don't need this array after the loop ends, do I need to free the array's space each time?
2. When I dynamically allocate memory for an array of strings, for example, do I also need to allocate memory for each of its elements (strings)?
3. Let's say i have these 2 dynamically allocated arrays:

```
char *** arr = { {....}, {....},{.....},.... };
char ** newArr = { ......... };
```

can I do this? (x is an index of arr):

```
arr[x] = newArr;
```

and if yes, what will happen to the memory of the previous element I just switched?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Show code for these three cases.

Comment: 1. yes. 2. yes. 3. they does not look like dynamically allocated arrays,

Comment: @SouravGhosh I meant theoretically, I just wanted to illustrate what they look like.

Comment: Do the individual elements of the array that `arr` points to each point to their own dynamically allocated memory block? And are these pointers your only copy of the addresses of these dynamically allocated memory blocks? If the answer to both questions is yes, then the line `arr[x] = newArr;` will cause a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), because by overwriting your only copy of the address of that memory block, you no longer know what is was, so you can no longer `free` it.

Comment: So do I need to ```free(arr[x])``` first?
And will I need to allocate new memory for it before assigning newArr to it?

Answer (score 1):

Your title uses the term dynamic memory *allocation*, whereas some if your detail questions use different terminology and / or use syntax that suggests automatic or static allocation instead.  Dynamic allocation involves directly or indirectly using an allocation function such as `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()`, and that is primarily what I will be talking about.

> 1. If I dynamically define an array inside a loop, and give it different values each time, and I also don't need this array after the
>    loop ends, do I need to free the array's space each time?

Yes.

Each dynamic *allocation* reserves space that is not already allocated at the time of the call, and that space remains allocated until you free it via `free()` or the program terminates, whichever comes first.  Until it frees that memory, then, the program has less available for future allocations, and if it keeps on allocating then it uses ever more memory.  Eventually, it will run out, and before then it is likely to cause performance problems or worse not only for itself, but for other processes, too.

The general rule is that every allocation must be paired with a corresponding free, though you can fudge that a bit for allocations that need to be retained until the program terminates anyway.

> 2. When I dynamically allocate memory for an array of strings, for example, do I also need to allocate memory for each of its elements
>    (strings)?

Maybe.

The question is ambiguous.  I suspect that by "strings" you mean pointers to `char`, but it is essential to understand that strings are null-terminated sequences of `char`s in memory -- thus, not pointers.  One *accesses* strings via pointers to them, but you must not confuse the pointer with the string to which it points.

If you allocate space in which to store pointers to strings, whether dynamically or otherwise, that yields space for the pointers, not for anything for them to point to.  You need to provide separately for the strings themselves.  That could mean allocating additional space for those dynamically, too, but it could also mean pointing to strings that were already allocated by some other means.

> 3. Let's say i have [...]
>
>    ```
>     char *** arr = { {....}, {....},{.....},.... };
>     char ** newArr = { ......... };
>    ```
>
>    can I do this? (x is an index of arr):
>
>    ```
>     arr[x] = newArr;
>    ```
>
>    and if yes, what will happen to the memory of the previous element I just switched?

Yes and nothing.

Regardless of how `arr` and `newArr` were allocated, yes, you can perform that assignment as long as `x` is a valid index into `arr`.  It replaces the pointer value stored in `arr[x]` with the pointer value that at that point is stored in `newArr`, leaving both pointers pointing to the same thing.  This has no effect on the data to which either the original value of `arr[x]` or its new value points.  In particular, **it does not cause any memory to be freed**, so if the original value of `arr[x]` pointed to dynamically allocated memory, and you have no other pointer to the same dynamically-allocated block, then that block can no longer be freed.  This is called a "memory leak".

Comment: Thank you very much, I just wanted to ask about (2):
So if I allocate memory for each of the strings array elements (array of char*), then i cant "physically" store strings in it, and otherwise i can only store the pointers to them?
and does the assignment syntax remain the same for both?
(for ex. char** arr, char* str, arr[2]=str)

Comment: @ItamarIvri, the allocation functions allocate the amount of space you request.  You can use that however you want.  But if you allocate space sized for *n* objects of type `char *`, and you use it to store *n* objects of type `char *`, then there is no space left over for anything else.  The allocation functions don't know anything about data types -- they deal strictly in sizes, measured in bytes.